# xml "reusable" code

Tags: javascript, xml

Is it possible to make a reusable xml code with some javascript inside? like an import or include. My problem is that I need to write different xml files and are almost all the same, what change is just some properties. Any best practice?
Thanks
Pietro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know any Java you could use Groovy, a Domain Specific Language on top of Java which has some very fancy XML creating/parsing features.  This would allow you to read your list of properties directly from a file.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Processing+XML

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate what you mean by change in properties? A best practice that you are looking for might be to run the xml through an xslt processor to change the value of the properties. Is this feasible in your situation?